# Pentaho User Console missing "MultipartEntityBuilder" for Modified Java Script Value

Tags: java, neo4j, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I try to upload the file to "www.abc.com" for that I using the "Modified Java Script Value" script to perform the work. My KTR file working fine PDI spoon, but it's not working on the Pentaho user console server. When I am running the same KTR file on the Pentaho User Console getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/NameValuePair;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:219)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.build(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:240)
at Processor.processRow(Processor.java:40)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.UserDefinedJavaClass.processRow(UserDefinedJavaClass.java:1018)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This same error was coming for PDI spoon too, for that I added "httpmime-4.5.9.jar" in the PDI lib folder. For Pentaho User Console I don't know how to fix this error or where to place this "httpmime-4.5.9.jar" file.

And for Kettle We did 'Search: Neo4j JDBC Connector' and install it from the marketplace, how to install for Pentaho User Console.